# Shopify carrier service

Tags: api, shopify, shopping-cart

I have created a carrier service:

```
$webhook_array = array(
        "carrier_service" => array(
            "name" => "Shipping Rate Provider",
            "callback_url"=> site_url."/carrierservice_test.php",
            "format"=> "json",
            "service_discovery" => true
        )
    );

$webhooks = $shopify('POST', '/admin/carrier_services.json', $webhook_array);
```

This code successfully creates a carrier service, but this carrier service does not hit my app.

The following is not called when the checkout page is accessed:

```
callback url "callback_url"=> site_url."/carrierservice_test.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to at least make it active. Do a put like:

```
PUT /admin/carrier_services/{{id}}.json
 {
   "carrier_service": {
   "id": {{id}},
   "active": true
   }}
```